# Flash (Flex Application) Generate HTML at Run Time for JavaScript/SignalR Communication

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, signalr

Sort of a high-level question, but looking for guidance. I have a Flash application that communicates via a TCP socket to a C++ application on a server. I'm looking to prototype replacing this socket with something like SignalR or Socket.io, preferably the former since we have some experience with it.

We may not necessarily have control over the actual HTML page, as it is sometimes managed by partners. My question is, specifically, whether the Flash can spawn an iframe or inject other HTML into the containing page that would host the SignalR JavaScript client. I'm familiar with the actual communication between Flash and JavaScript, but more concerned about the ability to generate and link the HTML/JavaScript at run time since we *may* not have access to the containing HTML source in all cases.

Comment: I'm not sure if your setup, but I've seen weird cross-domain errors accessing the enclosing HTML page if the SWF is not served from the same domain as the HTML page. Beyond that, in theory the Flash ExternalInterface should be able to execute JavaScript which will modify the HTML Page DOM to do things such as creating an iFrame. This is not a use case I have come across, so you'd have to run your own experiments to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure that `allowScriptAccess` is set to `always` in your markup to embed the SWF in the HTML page.  Using swfobject:

```
var params = {};
params.quality = "high";
params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
//other params
swfobject.embedSWF(
"project.swf", "flashContent",
"100%", "100%",
swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
flashvars, params, attributes);
```

See also http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/changes-allowscriptaccess-default-flash-player.html